# In Swift 2.1, how do you get the NSError that was thrown?

Tags: error-handling, exception, swift2, avcapturedevice

I'm initializing an AVCaptureDeviceInput. In Swift 2 rather than getting an NSError variable you catch an error with a do-try-catch sandwich. However I don't see how to get the NSError inside the catch part. The recommendation given [on Apple's developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19597) does not indicate how you can access the NSError.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
 var error: NSError?

        do {
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: [])
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            request.HTTPBody = nil
        }
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: I've done this a bunch of times, and it's still hard to remember... Such awkward syntax, IMO

Comment: It's just one of those ones that you add to your autocomplete snippets in XCode because otherwise you're just going to be coming back right here :D

Comment: @Karlos, why do you assign `nil` to `request.HTTPBody` ?

Comment: @bibscy: Its just an example.